# abstract declarator Node* used as declaration

Tags: c++

I am using an abstract class `SetOfInt`; where a Btree baseclass inherits from. The declaration of the virtual function find gives me a compiler error and I cannot figure out why?

This is the exact error:

> SetOfInt.h:21: error: expected unqualified-id before `'virtual'`
>   SetOfInt.h:21: error: abstract declarator `'Node*'` used as declaration
>   SetOfInt.h:21: error: expected `';'` before `'virtual'`
>   SetOfInt.h:30: error: expected unqualified-id before `'virtual'`
>   SetOfInt.h:30: error: abstract declarator `'Node*'` used as declaration
>   SetOfInt.h:30: error: expected `';'` before `'virtual'`

Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
/*  1 */ #include <cstdlib>
/*  2 */ #include <iostream>
/*  3 */
/*  4 */ using namespace std;
/*  5 */
/*  6 */ class Node
/*  7 */ {
/*  8 */ public:
/*  9 */     Node (int x);
/* 10 */     int m_data;
/* 11 */     Node *m_left;
/* 12 */     Node *m_right;
/* 13 */ };
/* 14 */
/* 15 */ class SetOfInt
/* 16 */ {
/* 17 */ public:
/* 18 */     void virtual add(int x)=0;
/* 19 */     bool virtual test(int x)=0;
/* 20 */     bool virtual remove(int x)=0;
/* 21 */     Node* virtual find(int x)=0;
/* 22 */ };
/* 23 */
/* 24 */ class Btree : public SetOfInt
/* 25 */ {
/* 26 */ public:
/* 27 */     void virtual add(int x);
/* 28 */     bool virtual test(int x);
/* 29 */     bool virtual remove(int x);
/* 30 */     Node* virtual find(int x);
/* 31 */     Node *m_root;
/* 32 */ };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return types should go after the `virtual` keyword.

i.e.

```
virtual void add(int x);
```

instead of

```
void virtual add(int x);
```

Comment: `void virtual add(int x);` is fine. The problem is with `Node* virtual find(int x);`, which should be `Node virtual *find(int x);` to stay with this style of writing the return type first.